# Ejecutar un script con contenido en formato crontab

Tags: php, html, bash, crontab

Es mi primer pregunta en el foro, les cuento porque quiero hacer esto, tengo un programita con vista en html para redirigir las llamadas entrantes de un numero de telefono a otro, seleccionamos la fecha/hora de pasaje, destinatario y por ultimo cuando vuelven las llamadas

El programa hace un pasaje de variables con **strtotime** y **date** y las guarda junto con el destinatario elegido en formato crontab en un archivo **datos.txt**

El archivo **datos.txt** se visualiza asi por ejemplo:

```
00 20    22 5 0   root    /root/pasar_a_emma
30 22    22 5 0   root    /root/volver_a_la_oficina
```

Como el programa no esta terminado, copio el contenido del **datos.txt** y lo pego en el crontab, que ejecuta los scripts **pasar_a_emma** y **volver_a_la_oficina** en el dia y horario que le escribo

La cuestion es que necesito que otras personas puedan hacer este pasaje de llamadas a través del html, entonces una de mis ideas era guardar los datos en un archivo bash y que el crontab lo chequee cada momento

```
* * * * *  root    /var/www/html/script.sh
```

Para esto, aunque suene un poco sucio, necesitaria que el crontab me ejecute este **script.sh** con contenido crontab de alguna manera, porque el crontab no se puede escribir directamente y en caso de que necesiten chequear o modificar de nuevo el pasaje voy a tener que usar un archivo accesible, que se pueda visualizar con html

Les agradezco cualquier aporte! Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta un `at` para programar una tarea para lanzar un `sh` el día y a la hora que quieras , no es necesario usar el archivo `crontab`.

En `php` :

```
exec("echo 'sh archivo.sh' | at  $dia.$mes.$año");
```

Para ver las tareas creadas desde la consola ejecutas el comando `atq`

Comment: Buenas tardes Fen , recien veo tu respuesta, estuve investigando un poco sobre el at el problema es que según entendido, las tareas con at se "borran" al reiniciar el pc o el servidor donde las almacene y necesito que sean persistentes